# Pascal error 'call by var for arg no.1 has to match exactly'

Tags: pascal

I learning to make a program that gets data from a txt file and places it in arrays.

the following are its types :

```
    type
          ekspedisi = record
          nmeksp : string; // Nama Ekspedisi
          jlp : string; // Jenis layanan pengiriman
          biaya : integer; // Biaya pengiriman per kg
          lp : integer; // per hari
          end;

         ekspedisiku = record
         nom : array [1..100] of ekspedisi;
         end;
```

and a simple algorithm

```
procedure getDaftarEkspedisi(var kirim : ekspedisiku);

var 
i,j,k : integer;
eksp : text;
init : string;
garis : array [1..100] of integer;
mark : string;
jeks : integer;
count : integer;

begin
assign(eksp,'ekspedisi.txt');
reset(eksp);
 i := 0;
 k := 1;
 j := 1;
 mark := '|';
 jeks := 10;

writeln('Loading ekspedisi.. ');
while(not(eof(eksp))) do
begin
readln(eksp,init);
i := i + 1;
    for j := 1 to length(init) do
        begin
            if init[j] = mark then
                begin 
                    garis[k] := j;
                    k := k + 1;
                end;
        end;
for i := 1 to jeks do
    begin
        count := ((i-1)*5);
        kirim.nom[i].nmeksp := copy(init,garis[1+count] + 2,garis[2+count]-garis[1+count]-2);
        kirim.nom[i].jlp := copy(init,garis[2+count] + 2,garis[3+count]-garis[2+count]-2);
        val(copy(init,garis[3+count] + 2,garis[4+count]-garis[3+count]-2),kirim.nom[i].biaya);
        val(copy(init,garis[4+count] + 2,garis[5+count]-garis[4+count]-2),kirim.nom[i].lp);
    end;
close(kirim);
writeln('loading sukses.');
end;
 end;
```

from that code, i get the following error

<166,13>Error: Call by var for arg no.1 has to match exactly : got "ekspedisiku" expected "Text"

curiously, line 166 is only

```
        close(kirim);
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the file handle to `close`, so:

`close(kirim);`

should be:

`close(eksp);`

It also looks like you're closing the file at the wrong place in your function. It should most likely be after the `while` loop, so you need to change:

```
close(kirim);
writeln('loading sukses.');
end;
end;
```

to:

```
  end;
close(kirim);
writeln('loading sukses.');
end;
```

Note that this mistake probably happened because your identation is messed up - if you're careful with formatting your code properly then you won't be so likely to make this kind of error.